# Main html page elements - ID or Class?

Tags: html, class

I've recently been looking into responsive design techniques / tutorials and have seen various different sources use both ID and Class attributes for their main page elements (Nav, Wrapper, Footer etc) and can't seem to find a detailed explanation and justification as to which should be used and why.

I understand the difference between them and where they should and shouldn't be used, but as far as I can tell it makes no difference which you use for the main elements like containers as there will most likely only ever be 1 or a couple instances of these.

One person tells me I should use ID's as they probably won't be used more than once, and the other will tell me to use classes for them but no one ever really gives me a logical reason for either.

I'm by no means an expert of web design and was hoping someone could inform me on this so I can stick with one or at least know when to use them interchangeably.

Thanks =)

Answer (score 1):

```
#id1 {color:red;}
.class1 {color:red;}
```

These two statements are the same. Although there are some rules to follow in HTML. An id can be used only once and a class can be used on several elements on the same document. You can use use a class for a single item but you can not use an id on multiple element. After it is up to you to see what is the rigor that you want in your programming.

Good practice :

```
<div id="title-of-my-page"></div>
<div class="one-article special-class-grey-gabarit"></div>
<div class="one-article special-class-red-gabarit"></div>
```

I can use for a specific class template. To distinguish one block section etc ...

Comment: +1 for the good practice example but these two statements are not exactly the same like that because the ID has more precedence than the class